# Why Find my iPhone application is built in such useless way?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone, mac-address

Today I lost my iPhone 3GS And I was trying to locate it using "Find My iPhone" app. But as we know, it rarely helps!

I was wondering why is it built in this way and why they didn't use a MAC address based search instead, so that even if someone removes your account and formats everything still  you can find it whenever the Phone connects to the internet using the unique MAC address.

I know this doesn't help me find my iPhone but at least it could give some ideas for future versions of this type of applications.

---

**EDIT**

And furthermore, why they don't add this function to the iOS core instead of running it as an app which can easily be disabled.

Comment: What makes you think MAC address isn't involved in how the program operates on iOS 6?

Comment: @bmike So if in that phone they change my Apple account to a new Apple account and they format everything and then connect to Internet can I still track it? (Of course by considering the fact that Find My iPhone app is not disabled yet)

Comment: iOS 6 doesn't have wipe then track functionality. iOS 7 continues to track if _you_ wipe it **and** if it's still connected to data somehow. You should be more angry at the carriers since they have IMEI/MEID data and the ability to track far better than Apple in the case of stolen device wipe and reuse. Newer hardware combined with iOS 7 also prevents the reactivation of reserved devices whether they are wiped or not.

Comment: Thank you for the information; Yes that is another point. But as I see IMEI is usually unique (and sometimes changeable), however the MAC is always unique (or to be accurate much harder to change). I think there need to be a stronger cooperation between Apple (smartphone companies) and telecom companies to provide a better facility in these occasions which actually I doubt happens in close future; By the way, I think if I should be angry with someone it is myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple realized they could make Find My iPhone work better and between hardware that supports iOS 7 and the new OS - activation lock does precisely what I think you ask.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TI174

The tracking doesn't require any app to be installed for iOS 7 or earlier OS and is baked into the settings app. The app only assists you in tracking from a remote device if you don't want to use the iCloud web interface for tracking and wiping.